# How to add a image button to a web view programmatically using image tag in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to add a button to a bottom corner of the view after all the content is displayed. how can I add the image tag to loadHtmlString at the bottom right corner of the web view.

Answer (score 0):

Set the button in the html itself under button tag and on its click event set the javascript that calls a function in iPhone.
or take a button in html tag ad set its type as submit. and from iPhone code you can get the submit button method in webview.

Try exploring webViews Property.

hAPPY cODING...